# Is there a size limit on objects being sent to a custom receiver app?

Tags: chromecast

Im trying to pass a decent sized object to my custom receiver app but it never seems to make it through. If I take a smaller object and do JSON.stringify it then it seems to work.  But regardless of if i stringify the parent object or not the sending never seems to work.

sender app

```
session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
```

receiver app

```
window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
    console.log('Message [' + event.senderId + ']: ' + event.data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a size limit, try not to get close to 64K. If you need to pass something larger, then you are using the wrong mechanism; the message bus is for small messages, mostly control messages and should not be treated or used as a data channel.

Comment: Is there something better built into the api that should be used as a data channel?

Comment: No, the idea is to get the data from the cloud; sender application should mostly be a "controller". If it needs to send larger data (say, local media), you need to set up a web server in your sender and approach it that way. Of course you can break a large data into smaller pieces and use the data channel t transfer piece by piece  but that is not recommended and is a lot more work than the other option. What sort of (large) data do you need to send?

Comment: I actually just switched it over so I make a request to my server from the receiver app instead of trying to pass it from the sender app.

Comment: I'm trying to stream audio visualization data to the Chromecast since audio analysis isn't supported in receiver apps. Already setup a Web Socket server to be an in-between from the desktop but I'm looking for a cleaner peer-to-peer solution. Surprisingly, WebRTC isn't supported either.

Comment: @AliNaddaf What about in the case where the cast receiver is the media provider? In my case, the receiver JS loads the media and renders it into a video element. However, I would like to push an image down to the sender for display within the application. What would be the best approach to push images down to the device from the receiver?

Comment: As long s you use the message bus to communicate, that would be the limit. If possible, one solution would be for your receiver to upload the content (image) to a web server of yours, with some obfuscated name, and then communicate the url (and token/keys or whatever is needed) to the phone and instruct the phone where to get the image. It is somewhat indirect but it works best for multiple devices as well, and practically is the way to go.