# iOS Google Cast Session Keep Suspending

Tags: google-cast

I am developing an iOS app with SDK v 3.2. All is OK, problem is with loading long list in queue (50 tracks).. it keeps suspend and resume but in resume the player state is 0 and not getting updated again. It works fine with less tracks say 10 to 15. Please suggest cause and solution of the problem.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have reached the [limit](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages). The transport message maximum size is currently 64 KBytes. As stated by Ali Naddaf in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749955/5832311). *Yes, there is a size limit, try not to get close to 64K. If you need to pass something larger, then you are using the wrong mechanism; the message bus is for small messages, mostly control messages and should not be treated or used as a data channel.* You may also check this related SO post: [What is the maximum size of a message in the Cast SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753780/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-message-in-the-cast-sdk)